# snipe more than one older message using discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a snipe command that fetches more than one deleted message that was sent earlier in a specific channel. For now, all I can do is snipe the last deleted message. This is my code :

```js
const msg = client.snipes.get(message.channel.id);
if (!msg) return message.channel.send('There is no message to snipe. :eyes:')

const snipeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
  .setDescription(msg.content)

message.channel.send(snipeEmbed);
```

Now, that part of the code works perfectly fine, can someone show me how to do it with **more than one** deleted message ? I'm trying to make it so I could type "-snipe 2" to get the second oldest message that has been deleted. I don't know if I was clear or not, but help would be appreciated !

Comment: You could make the keys of `client.snipes` *arrays* of messages instead of just one message

Comment: @Lioness100 How can I do that ? Sorry, I'm new to coding so that's why...

Comment: Please provide more info about the structure of `client.snipes`.

Comment: @user15517071 What do you mean ?